# How to prevent users to download HTML template from demo?

Tags: html, css

I want to sell HTML templates so I have to create a demo page. If I create a demo page, users can download it and they don't buy it. So How people sell HTML templates? How can I prevent users to download templates from my demo page?

Comment: You could just use photos of said templates.

Comment: @jay-hales I can't. because in ThemeForest and other markets I have to create a demo for users

Comment: why don't you add demo images on your page, so that they cannot download html code. Or Demo Videos.
On other options you will have to create pages in angular or any other frontend platform which can encrypt template data.

Comment: This question is not on-topic. See the [help/dont-ask]. This question is not about programming, it's about how to prevent other people from programming.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:
You can’t.

Anything that reached to browser(client side) or can be seen by user that can be downloaded anyhow. The web page is visible that means the HTML code is executed and you can easily inspect it or view the source code.

The ‘hacky’ answer:

You can disable the context menu and some keys like so:

```
 <body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
   <script>
    document.onkeydown = function (e) { 
            if (event.keyCode == 123) { 
                return false; 
            } 
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)) { 
                return false; 
            } 
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)) { 
                return false; 
            } 
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)) { 
                return false; 
            } 
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)) { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
   </script>
 </body>
```

But if someone really wanted to get your code, they could just disable js and none of this would work.

The less ‘hacky’ answer:

You can just minify you code. This won’t hide your code but this will make it harder for people to copy bits of it and such. You can use this:
https://www.willpeavy.com/tools/minifier/

You could also use a lot of spaces so the code isn’t seen unless the user scrolls to the right, but I don’t recommend this.

The real answer:

Don’t try. Just use images, otherwise, people will be able to copy it no matter what you tried.